# PyCharm auto-import Fails To Import Properly

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I have an app structured like so:

```
api/
|_app/
    |_ __init__.py
    |_conf/
    |_resources/
        |_ __init__.py
        |_controller.py
    |_dao/
        |_ __init__.py
        |_thing_dao.py
    |_etc...
```

I want to use the function `get_thing_by_id` in `thing_dao.py` inside of `controller.py`.  In PyCharm I start to type `get_thing_by_id` and it prompts me to auto-import the function.  The problem is it simply does `from thing_dao import get_thing_by_id` but when I attempt to run the app (Flask) I get `ImportError: No module named 'thing_dao'`.  What I end up having to do is a relative import or start at the module level `from app.dao.thing_dao import get_thing_by_id`.

I suspect this issue is related to my project structure and less of a PyCharm bug.  Is there a way I could structure my project to better hint to PyCharm how to do imports?  I've looked through the configuration option for auto-imports and PyCharm and they're quite slim so I suspect that I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered I had my directories marked as a "Source Root".  Unmarking them made the imports work properly.